# Хорошая практика при работе с $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Приветс. Я делаю генератор эльфийских имен, для этого вытаскиваю с сервера `ajax`'ом эльфийский словарь при загрузке странички, и затем работаю с ним. Есть несколько вопросов:

1. Этот словарь вытаскивается прям к клиенту в браузер (в каком-либо виде)?
2. Если да, то это хорошая тактика? Так вообще делают? Словарь весит 100кб.
3. Если я буду вытаскивать таким же образом еще штук 5 словарей такого же размера, это нормально?

Вытаскиваю я его следующим кодом:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $.get('/data', function(data) {
        window.quenyaDictionary = data;
    });
});
```

4. Нормально ли использовать `window.quenyaDictionary = data`? Я читал, что лучше такого не делать. Можно ли вытащить словарь каким-то другим способом так, чтобы им можно было пользоваться за пределами `callback function`?

Спасибо!

Comment: наверное все же надо составлять имя на бэкэнде

Comment: @StrangerintheQ простите, а что это значит? Я прям совсем новичок.

Comment: вам предлагают составлять имя (генерировать) не на стороне клиента(браузера), а на стороне сервера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое не совсем понятно.

В браузер словарь поступает с результатом запроса в том виде, в котором вы его отдаете на сервере. Часто для таких целей используют формат [JSON](https://learn.javascript.ru/json).

Почему бы и нет? 500 кб не такой уж и большой объем, к примеру вес минифицированной (сжатой версии) ***Jquery*** составляет около 85кб, при этом вы можете включить кеширование словарей на клиенте, что позволит сэкономить трафик пользователя. Пример запроса с кешированием:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/data",
  cache: true
}).done(function() {
  alert('Success');
});
```

Где `cache: true`  -  включает кеширование запроса

Да, не стоит использовать `window.quenyaDictionary = data`, вот хороший пример как сделать тоже самое без `window`:

```js
let quenyaDictionary;
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $.get('/data', function(data) {
        quenyaDictionary = data;
    });
});

console.log('Данные доступны вне callback:', quenyaDictionary);
```

Советую вам почитать об области видимости переменных, чтобы в будущем не задавать такие вопросы. Ознакомится можно например [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const)

Так же хочу привлечь внимание к [localstorage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage) в нем можно хранить данные на клиенте, например в целях кеширования.

Comment: Спасибо! По поводу области видимости - я, приблизительно, знаком. Но меня совершенно выбила из колеи асинхронность, никогда с ней не сталкивался. Почему-то казалось, что я должен непременно инициализировать переменную внутри функции.

Comment: По поводу асинхронности стоит почитать про Promise API. Крайне полезная вещь и сейчас всюду.